# Mathematical Rounding depending on decimal value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, math, rounding

I am inserting minute values into a new table from the query. The new table has two columns: [Minutes] that is inserted, the other column has a calculated value which converts minutes to hours. I need to use mathematical rounding when converting into hours so, for example 2.58 should be 3 hours and 6.25 should become 6 hours.
I am using ROUND function but for some reason it always rounds numbers down. Even if I use FLOOR and CEILING it always rounds 2.58 to 2
Below is my sample code.

```
    CREATE TABLE [mytable](
[Minutes] [int] NULL,
[Hours]  AS (case when [Minutes]>(0) then ROUND([Minutes]/(60),0) else (0) end)
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    INSERT INTO [mytable]([Minutes])
    VALUES ('155')

    INSERT INTO [mytable]([Minutes])
    VALUES ('375')
```

Comment: Use `Hours AS (CASE WHEN Minutes > 0 THEN ROUND(1.0*Minutes/60,0) ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: Or: `Hours AS (CASE WHEN Minutes > 0 THEN (Minutes+30)/60 ELSE 0 END)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do one of two things,

1) change the datatype of the Minutes column to decimal or

2) change your case statement and cast the minutes value to a decimal before doing any math on it

your statement could look something like this

```
case when [Minutes] > 0 then round (cast([Minutes] as decimal)  /60,0 ) else 0 end
```

Comment: Thanks, all of the suggestions works for me. I really appreciate your help